# aspx Behind Code Video Tutorial of Sharepoint Online for beginner

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

i wish you are have good tutrial for beginner regarding, how programmatically aspx page behind code of sharepoint online. i already read saveral tutorial but i dont understand where i am should start to write my behind code.

thanks very much for your helping.

Regard,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Online can use Rest API to do CRUD operation to list in site page:

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-list-items-using-rest-api-services-in-shar/)

[SharePoint Rest API Crud Operations](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-rest-api-crud-operations/)

Comment: Dear @jerry thanks for anwer. but not CSOM that i needed. I need to the way to coding behind code (.cs) in the .aspx file (site pages) folder.

ex : if i have test.aspx (in the site pages) as user interface which in this file occour CRUD operation to a list.

Comment: @faridwahyu, if want to do CRUD operation in a aspx site page, it's suggested to use SharePoint Rest API achieve. I will update answer, please check later. Thanks

Comment: hmm its interesting to use JSOM ..
as i know (CMIIW) JSOM is client script. but is it posible we use c# (.cs) files for CRUD operations?

Comment: C# .cs file can't be used to use with SharePoint aspx site page, it's usually used in Console Application or Provider Hosted Add-in. So for SharePoint Online site page, JSOM/Rest API is the best option.

Comment: owh... I see.. thanks for you explanation.. so the best way for CRUD operation JSOM / Rest API. i am glad to know this.

Comment: You are welcome and I suggest you could accept as answer if the reply is helpful to the question. Thanks :)